# How do I transfer an Postgres SQL Function from a 9.3 DB to another computer with same version?

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, transfer

I have a working function that was created and want to just transfer it to another newly installed Postgres DB.

I have checked around and seeing command line options which seems kinda of dry for a common task?

Is there a module import / export option?

I have exported the function into a .sql file from the database, so just looking for an import option.

I know very little about Postgres :)

Comment: The easiest way is to use pgadmin to export then import the function

Answer (score 0):

How did you export it?  If it exported as sql into a file named file_name.sql, you would just do:

```
psql -f file_name.sql
```

With whatever additional parameters are needed to connect to the correct server and database.